# Сохранение в файл Unity

Tags: разработка-игр, unity3d

В самом Unity, когда запускаю игру все нормальное сохраняет, а когда скомпилировал в .exe, то никуда не сохраняет, как исправить? Чтобы сохраняло уже при скомпилированной игре

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class GetName : MonoBehaviour {

    public string filename = "";
    public Name Char;
    public string playerName;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
       filename = "PlayerName.txt";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnGUI()
    {    
        Name Namest = (Name)Char.GetComponent("Name");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 110, 90, 100), "Your name:");
        playerName = GUI.TextField(new Rect(90, 110, 100, 20), playerName);

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(200, 110, 50, 20), "Save"))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("PlayerName.txt");
            sw.WriteLine(playerName);
            sw.Close();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы покажите код, в котором  вы что и как пытаетесь сохранить, а мы подскажем что-то

Comment: Прикрепил код к вопросу

Comment: Запись стандартная. Попробуйте сделать то, что написано в ответе..... Например поставить `try/catch` и в catch попробовать что-то в GUI вывести. Вдруг ошибка записи...что скорее всего...т.к. изначально файла нет, а его надо создать....я что-то не уверен, что `StreamWriter` создает файл в случае его отсутствия......ибо создавать надо примерно так `File.CreateText(path)`.......директорию другую поставить тоже пробуйте, например `Data/Save/test.txt`

Comment: а собираете то вы под какую платформу? А то некоторые платформы некоторые реализации попросту не поддерживают.

Answer (score 3):

1. Попробуйте отловить исключение, мне кажется, что оно создаёт вам проблемы.
   Так же, советую использовать `AppDomain` для обработки необработанных исключений.
2. Не советую сохранять файл таким способом, укажите более конкретный путь вашему файлу.
3. Попробуйте загрузить файл из кода и узнайте его путь, возможно он сериализируется в каком то другом пути. Например в папке `Temp`.
4. Так же используйте класс `Application` и его свойства `persistentDataPath`, `streamingAssetsPath`.

Answer (score 2):

Возможные проблемы при сохранении:

- происходит ли у вас исключительная ситуация? Если происходит - "отловите" ее и ищите решение для нее.
- происходит сохранение, но в другое место. Попробуйте для теста указать полный путь в нужную директорию и убедитесь происходит ли сохранение в нее (предворительно убедитесь, что в данную директорию есть разрешение на запись).
- особенности места сохранения для разных платформ. Попробуйте в пути сохранения указать еще и Application.persistentDataPath.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сохранить файл в другом месте. например

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:/PlayerName.txt"); // для ПК
либо так, для различных платформ (win, macos, ios, android и т.д.)
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + @"/PlayerName.txt");
```

Последний вариант оптимальный и правильный будет если расчитываете на различные платформы собирать проект.
В общем вот.